# Setting up cron job with custom events in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron

I have set up my magento 2 (2.2.0-dev) store with sample data. I am totally new to magento. I have a simple requirement where I have to add random products, customers, reviews and actions on those reviews every day. I am planning to set a cron job to do that. In went to cron (Scheduled Tasks) under `Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System`. Figured out that one can set cron jobs for events like sending mails, updating currency rates.

> My question is, is it even possible to set up cron jobs that add random products, customers, reviews etc ? If yes, please guide me how to do that.

Any lead, reference will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure it is possible, but you have to create a module for importing them and then set up a cron job to execute the php scenario.

Comment: Great. Can you tell me some links where it shows how I can access products, and push the code to DB ?